# How to center items in a Java combobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, renderer

Is there a method for a combobox in Java that will center the items in the combobox? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
myCombobox.setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is a better answer here [How to let the content in JComboBox display in the center?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084188/how-to-let-the-content-in-jcombobox-display-in-the-center)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this link: [How to Use Combo Boxes (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Using Swing Components)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

```
class ComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel
                   implements ListCellRenderer {
  public ComboBoxRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);
    setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
  }
  //. . .
```

or

```
((JLabel)comboBox.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have look at `Renderers` concept, described about in the [JTable tutorial on Oracles pages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), thic concept is similair for `JComboBox`, `JList`, `JTable` and `JTree`, in the `Renderer` you can centering desired text