# How to let the content in JComboBox display in the center?

Tags: java, swing, center, jcombobox, cellrenderer

Currently I have this `JComboBox`, how can I get to center the content inside it?

```
String[] strs = new String[]{"15158133110", "15158133124", "15158133458"};
JComboBox com = new JComboBox(strs);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create a Renderer then apply it to the JComboBox

```
DefaultListCellRenderer dlcr = new DefaultListCellRenderer(); 
dlcr.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultListCellRenderer.CENTER); 
com.setRenderer(dlcr);
```

also import this,

```
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
```

Comment: I'm glad you got to that before I (foolishly) suggested HTML formatting.  Now I can pretend I was never going to say that.  ;)

Comment: I'd go further than 'much simpler'. Your answer is better classified as 'correct approach'.  HTML formatting is a hack.

Answer (score 1):

```
((JLabel)jComboBox1.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Try This